# "proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx" verses "proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:xxxx"

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I noticed that 2 apps behind my NGINX reverse proxy require specifying a `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:xxxx;` instead of `proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;`.  All the other apps don't have any issues with using `proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;`

For example, if I use the below config for one of those 2 apps...

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8585;
```

I'll get the 2 error/warn messages, respectively:

```
2023/04/30 21:29:47 [error] 75328#71672: *1 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.1, server: alwaysup.mydomain.com, request: "GET /login HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8585/login", host: "alwaysup.mydomain.com"
2023/04/30 21:29:47 [warn] 75328#71672: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.1, server: alwaysup.mydomain.com, request: "GET /login HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8585/login", host: "alwaysup.mydomain.com"
```

Why can't I use `localhost` for those 2 apps?  Would it be better if I use `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:xxxx` for everything in NGINX or try to configure the 2 odd-ball apps somehow to use `proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;`?

Comment: This behavior is noticed when if in case your both the apps are bound to specific IPs rather than all interfaces "0.0.0.0". when we bind apps with specific ips. it will listen for events on that ips only (127.0.0.1 or ::1). a possible solution is to change both of your app bindings to "0.0.0.0" or continue calling apps with 192.xxxx (This again has an issue that this IP must be static). Let me know if this works. I post this as an answer.

Comment: @SuchandraT This is what I thought at first.  But when I checked one of my apps, it was already binding to `0.0.0.0`.  I even tried changing it to `127.0.0.1`.  It only works when NGINX is pointing to the static IP.  Here's a sceenshot of the app:  https://imgur.com/a/ZWV3kEt

Comment: @SuchandraT I looked a little further down the settings; and, saw the below settings; which are intended to suppress the authentication prompt from within my LAN:  https://imgur.com/a/uNbh0ft  Maybe, that's what's preventing NGINX from connecting to 0.0.0.0 aka localhost?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not localhost. localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 as loopback interface

Comment: Thanks.  So, from the 2 screenshots I posted, does it look like there's a way to configure the app to listen on all interfaces?